# How to reset object permissions to default?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I've just been added to a project using Postgresql 11.4 where database security has been an afterthought.  As part of tightening things up, I've used `ALTER DEFAULT PERMISSIONS` to set sane ACLs on any new objects (schemas, tables, functions, sequences) created.  However, there are hundreds of existing objects already in this database with wacko permissions.

Is there a command that will reset the permissions of an object (or group of objects) to the defaults (as seen with `\ddp`)?  Something like the equivalent of `REASSIGN OWNED` for object ownership, but instead for acls.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is directly modifying the system catalog tables.

To remove all permissions from `s.tab`, you can

```
UPDATE pg_class
SET relacl = NULL
WHERE oid = 's.tab'::regclass;
```

But then you also have to remove the dependencies between the table and all roles which had privileges on the table:

```
DELETE FROM pg_shdepend
WHERE classid = 'pg_class'::regclass
  AND refclassid = 'pg_authid'::regclass
  AND objid = 's.tab'::regclass
  AND deptype = 'a';
```

Needless to say, this is *very* dangerous, and I cannot guarantee that I didn't forget anything…

Comment: Thanks, but that seems a bit too risky.  I guess I can open a feature request...

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't do that either. You can code something on the client side to make the repetitive work less.